# Rails - Calculate hours on multiple records of each day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have time records submitted on every work day of the week. I need to calculate overtime done on a particular day. If @timesheet.sheet hours are greater than 8 then find the amount >8 and add to a @timesheet.overtime variable.

My problem is some people submit 2 sheets on one day. eg 7:30 till 11:30 job 1 and 12 to 6:30 job 2.

**This is what i am trying to achieve:**

This failed cause i cant compare it using :date.strftime("%A") and not sure how to find the difference and only sum that amount...

```
     days = 7.times
      days.each do |day|
        today = Date::DAYNAMES[day]
        @dailysheets = @timesheet.sheets.where(:date.strftime("%A") == today)
        @overtime =+ @dailysheets.sum(:hours)

      end
```

Said in words below the explain what im trying to achieve

```
foreach day of the week do 
       put @timesheet.sheets that match dayofweek into a day variable then
         Add the @sheet.hours fields together
         If combined records > 8 then
         add the difference to a overtime variable.
     end
```

Here is the code:

```
class Sheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :worknotes, dependent: :destroy
end  

class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :timesheet_rows, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :sheets, through: :timesheet_rows
end
```

The Sheet db model looks like this

```
 t.string   "jobNumber"
t.string   "stage"
t.date     "date"
t.decimal  "hours"
t.time     "start",      default: '2000-01-01 07:00:00'
t.time     "finish",     default: '2000-01-01 15:30:00'
t.boolean  "breakTaken", default: true
t.boolean  "overTime",   default: false
t.integer  "job_id"
t.datetime "created_at",                                 null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                                 null: false
t.integer  "user_id"
t.boolean  "active",     default: true
t.integer  "account_id"
```

Comment: Show the code you've got already, please

Comment: @Michael - Code updated

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how many timesheets one sends. You have a separate table for that which has a user_id foreign key linked to the Users table.

Then every input sent will be stored under their user_id like this:

TIME_SHEETS TABLE

```
id     user_id     time_in   time_out

1      34           08:00      12:00

2      74           09:00      23:00

3      34           14:00      18:00
```

and then it is a simple array iteration to get all that

elapsed_seconds = `((time_out - time_in) * 24 * 60 * 60).to_i`

or

```
diff = time_out - time_in
Date.day_fraction_to_time(diff) # => [h, m, s, frac_s]
```

in SQL you would do something like this:

```
select sum `((time_out - time_in) * 24 * 60 * 60).to_i` group_by user_id
```

that should give you the accumulated number of seconds worked overtime for each employee exploited by the boss.

Comment: I already have the data and the table it is just how to group them once you have the data. I will post my code when i get back

Answer (score 0):

The way i found the overtime was to get what days were worked, then if the total was over 8 hours per worked day then OT = the amount over

```
@workeddays = []

  @c = 0

  @timesheet.sheets.each do |sheet|
    sheetday = sheet.date.strftime('%A')
    @workeddays.push(sheetday) unless @workeddays.include?(sheetday)
  end

  @c = @workeddays.count
  @amount = 8 * @c
  check = @timesheet.total_hours - @amount

  if check >= 0
   @totalothrs = @timesheet.total_hours - @amount
  else
    @totalothrs = 0
  end
```

Im sure there is some refactoring in here but this works well